# typechecking AgGridReact

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I use Typescript with ag-grid with the following configuration.

```
typescript@3.9.6
@ag-grid-community/react@23.2.1
@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules@23.2.1
```

I've also used:

```
typescript@3.9.6
ag-grid-community@23.2.1
ag-grid-enterprise@23.2.1
ag-grid-react@23.2.1
```

In both cases, the following code fails to typecheck. Note that the code is taken almost verbatim from the online documentation at https://www.ag-grid.com/react-column-configuration/:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from '@ag-grid-community/react';

export class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      columnDefs: [
        { headerName: "Make", field: "make", sortable: true, filter: true}
      ],
      rowData: [
        { make: "Toyota"},
        { make: "Ford"},
        { make: "Porsche"}
      ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ag-theme-alpine">
        <AgGridReact
            columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
            rowData={this.state.rowData}>
        </AgGridReact>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Typescript complains with:

```
ERROR in /home/.../filename.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in /home/....tsx(23,40)
  TS2339: Property 'columnDefs' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.

ERROR in /home/.../filename.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in /home/.../tsx (24,37)
  TS2339: Property 'rowData' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.
```

How can I get past this type-checking error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me was importing the following type:

```
import { ColDef } from 'ag-grid-community';
```

... and then typing the `columnDefs` as `ColDef[]`. That got rid of the type-checking problem.

Comment: If you examine the error their code produces, it is a problem with accessing a non-existent property `columnDefs` and `rowData` on the `state`

Answer (score -1):

It's not a problem with the `ag-grid`, it is about how you defined your component. In your code you say:

```js
export class Test extends React.Component {
 // ...
}
```

If you look at the definition of `React.Component` type you'll see that it is generic and can accept up to three type arguments:

```
interface Component<P = {}, S = {}, SS = any> {
 // ...
}
```

The first type argument, `P`, is the type of the props. The second one, `S` is the type of the state, the third one, `SS`, is the type of state snapshot, something you don't need to care very much in your example.

Since you are not providing any type arguments to `React.Component`, TypeScript uses the default ones (`{}` for props and `{}` for state):

```js
// To TypeScript your code looks like:
export class Test extends React.Component<{}, {}, {}> {
 //                                           ^
 //                              This is the type of your state
}
```

**So TypeScript thinks the `state` of your component is `{}` and therefore has no property `columnDefs` or `rowData`!**

To fix this, provide a type of your `state`:

```js
interface TestState {
  columnDefs: SomeColumnType[];
  rowData: SomeRowObject[];
}

// You should also maybe define a type for props but that's not your question
export class Test extends React.Component<{}, TestState> {
  // WORKS!!!
}
```

Comment: This is plainly wrong. The typechecking problem is for AgGridReact, not my own component.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus As Oliver Cromwell said: "I beseech you, in the bowels of Christ, think it possible you may be mistaken". I made a small code sandbox for you with a working solution based on my answer. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-2euji?file=/src/index.tsx:116-117

Comment: Also please be more considerate with your words, this is a community of people who love coding and are keen to help each other. Being respectful is a vital part of the survival strategy of such communities.

Comment: The critical part of your working solution is based on my answer, not yours. I stand my ground; the problem is not in the typing of class Test. I believe you are confused about why your solution works. It's got nothing to do with the typing of my component __at all__ as my component is not called. It is the AgGridReact component that get's called and all that's needed is supplying the type of `columnDefs` that's used in the call to the AgGridReact component. Typing the Test component itself is a red herring.

Comment: Also, saying that something is "plainly wrong" is NOT disrespectful.

Comment: The crucial part is that the state is typed correctly, that is achieved by typing your component correctly. As state is not accessible from outside, nothing would change if you "called" your component. I am glad you found a solution though, I would recommend looking at the error message "TS2339: Property 'columnDefs' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'" again and trying to find out where the Readonly<{}> comes from, I bet that will shed some light into the problem.